# Webpack bundled express app fails to lookup view

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, babeljs

I run `npm run start` and server is running fine. When I attempt to view client at `localhost`, server returns error:
GET / 500 62.700 ms - 2028
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/views"

The application runs fine when just using source files. This error occurs when running application from webpack bundle.

What are the differences between source and bundled files that would make this error occur?

- npm:3.8.2
- node: 4.2.6
- express: 4.13.1
- webpack: 1.12.13
- babel-loader: 6.2.4

`webpack.config.js`

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(function(x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  });

module.exports = [
  {
    entry: {
      'app_bundle': './server.js'
    },
    target: 'node',
    query: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      presets: ['es2015']
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'babel',
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    output: {
      path: './',
      filename: '[name].js'
    },
    externals: nodeModules
  },
  {
    entry: [
      './src/index.jsx'
    ],
    target: 'web',
    query: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      presets: ['es2015']
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: 'style!css!autoprefixer'
        },
        { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,  loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
        { test: /\.ttf$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
        { test: /\.eot$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
        { test: /\.svg$/,    loader: "file-loader" }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'react': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react')
      },
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/public',
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'webpack_bundle.js'
    }
  }
];
```

The error trace tells me that the error is being handled by the production error handler in my `app.js` file:

```
// production error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.log(err);
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});
```

I console.log the error with the following output:

```
{ [Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/views"]
  view: 
   View {
     defaultEngine: 'ejs',
     ext: '.ejs',
     name: 'error',
     root: '/views',
     engine: [Function],
     path: undefined } }
```

View engine setup

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

I'm not sure how to start debugging...

Comment: Do you have a file called `error.ejs` in the `/views` folder of your app? Seems like express can't find the view template.

Comment: @cjhveal Thank you for the question. Yes, I have an `error.ejs` file in the `/views` folder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the answer lies in how webpack handles the special `__dirname` global variable. Webpack's default behavior is to replace `__dirname` with the "mock" value `/`. This can be seen in the error you get from express where it's looking for a file at the `root` of `/views`, not `./views`.

The solution is to add the following section to your webpack configuration:

```
node: {
  __dirname: true
}
```

Here's the docs which explain this behavior:
https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node